# Как нарисовать текст нa Canvas по высоте View

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Есть `view` в которой я на канвасе хочу написать текст.

Сначала я в `paint` устанавливаю размер текста равный высоте вьюхи и тут же возможно я делаю ошибку, мне не понятно:

```
this.fontSize = getHeight();
this.paint.setTextSize(fontSize);

Rect textBounds = new Rect();
this.paint.getTextBounds(myText, 0, myText.length(), textBounds);
```

После чего я рисую текст:

```
canvas.drawText(
                myText,
                canvas.getWidth() - textBounds.width(),
                canvas.getClipBounds().top + textBounds.height(),
                paint);
```

Но текст получаеться по высоте меньше чем  сама вьюха.
Вывожу в логи:

```
fontSize = 32                
textBounds.height() = 22
```

Вопрос как можно установить размер текста так, что  бы он был такого же размера по высоте как и сама  `view`?

Comment: ?Layout.LayoutParams params = (?Layout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams(); int height = params.height;

Comment: пардон, но комментарий бесполезный.

Comment: Получение высоты чего не то

Comment: я знаю как получить высоту вьюхи, вопрос в том, как установить в paint размер текста так, что бы он соответствовал высоте вьюхи. textBounds.height() возвращает значение высоты меньше чем я устанавливал в paint!

Comment: Возможно дело в метрике (px и т.п.)